# I got an ugly table instead of a sharp and neat one!

Tags: tables

This is a piece of code that I'm using to implement my desired table, but I got unwanted extra lines at the left side of the table.

Also, I want to call the table "Table 1", but LaTeX keeps calling that "Tab. 1" instead.

I really appreciate your help.

```
\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\begin{tabular*}{0.9\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill} } | c | c | c | c | c |}
\hline
Time - Angle & $45^{\circ}$ & $90 ^{\circ}$ & $180^{\circ} $ &  $360^{\circ}$ \\
\hline 
0.5 s & 44.22  & 192.71 & 1002.9  & 4118.2\\
\hline
1 s & 12.68 & 41.33  &  157.81 & 650.87 \\
\hline
2 s & 7.14 & 23.47 & 72.51 & 182.65\\
\hline
4 s & 4.41 &  14.43 & 32.05 & 109.12 \\
\hline
\end{tabular*}
\renewcommand{\tablename}{Table 1}
\caption{cost functions}
\label{Table:1}
\end{table}
```

Comment: "Tab." vs. "Table" is defined by the document class or some package.  so we need to know what you're using.

Comment: Please submit a compilable example instead of code snippets. What `\documentclass` are you using?

Comment: @barbarabeeton I'm using \documentclass[12pt, letterpaper, oneside]{thesis} and also array, multirow and multicol package.

Comment: @AboAmmar I would, but I don't know how to do that!

Comment: @Milad http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3343/what-makes-a-good-mwe

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you use `@{<stuff>}`, `<stuff>` is used for the column separation. You've supplied

```
@{\extracolsep{\fill} }
```

Note the space that is *included*. Remove this space.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
  \centering
  \begin{tabular*}{0.9\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} | c | c | c | c | c |}
    \hline
    Time - Angle & $45^{\circ}$ & $90 ^{\circ}$ & $180^{\circ} $ &  $360^{\circ}$ \\
    \hline 
    0.5 s & 44.22  & 192.71 & 1002.9  & 4118.2 \\
    \hline
    1 s & 12.68 & 41.33  &  157.81 & 650.87 \\
    \hline
    2 s & 7.14 & 23.47 & 72.51 & 182.65 \\
    \hline
    4 s & 4.41 &  14.43 & 32.05 & 109.12 \\
    \hline
  \end{tabular*}
  \caption{cost functions}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Here is a [`booktabs`](http://ctan.org/pkg/booktabs) edition:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{booktabs,siunitx}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{
      c % Time - Angle
      S[table-format = 2.2] % 45 degrees
      S[table-format = 3.2] % 90 degrees
      S[table-format = 4.2] % 180 degrees
      S[table-format = 4.2] % 360 degrees
      }
    \toprule
         & \multicolumn{4}{c}{Angle} \\
    \cmidrule(lr){2-5}
    Time & $\ang{45}$ & $\ang{90}$ & $\ang{180} $ & $\ang{360}$ \\
    \midrule
    \SI{0.5}{\second} & 44.22 & 192.71 & 1002.9  & 4118.2  \\
    \SI{1.0}{\second} & 12.68 &  41.33 &  157.81 &  650.87 \\
    \SI{2.0}{\second} &  7.14 &  23.47 &   72.51 &  182.65 \\
    \SI{4.0}{\second} &  4.41 &  14.43 &   32.05 &  109.12 \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
  \caption{cost functions}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: ...speaking of ugly, I'm working on a [`booktabs`](http://ctan.org/pkg/booktabs) version...

Comment: Thank you so much. It was really tricky to catch it! But still LaTeX keep labeling the table as "Tab. 1". Do you think if I use another document class that might help?

Comment: @Milad -- the `thesis` class contains this definition: `\def\tableshortname{Tab.}`  so if you redefine `\tableshortname` to "Table" that will likely fix it.

Comment: @Werner thanks a lot. It works pretty well. Just one more question, how can I align the numbers to the center in each cell?

Comment: @Milad If you want neat tables, use booktabs as shown above. If you want to center the numbers instead of aligning them by the decimal sign, simply replace every `S[table-format = 2.2]` by `c` – but be warned, it's gonna be ugly again.

Answer (score 2):

There are two lines in the `thesis` class responsible for this `Tab 0.1`. these are

```
\def\tableshortname{Tab.}
\renewcommand{\thetable}{\thechapter.\@arabic\c@table}
```

So, you need to undo these two lines by issuing

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\thetable}{\@arabic\c@table}
\makeatother
\renewcommand\tableshortname{Table}
```

The horizontal line in the header is also from the thesis class.

```
\documentclass[12pt, letterpaper, oneside]{thesis}
\usepackage{lmodern,fontspec,array, multirow, multicol}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\thetable}{\@arabic\c@table}
\makeatother
\renewcommand\tableshortname{Table}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\begin{tabular*}{0.9\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}| c | c | c | c | c |}
\hline
Time - Angle & $45^{\circ}$ & $90 ^{\circ}$ & $180^{\circ} $ &  $360^{\circ}$ \\
\hline 
0.5 s & 44.22  & 192.71 & 1002.9  & 4118.2\\
\hline
1 s & 12.68 & 41.33  &  157.81 & 650.87 \\
\hline
2 s & 7.14 & 23.47 & 72.51 & 182.65\\
\hline
4 s & 4.41 &  14.43 & 32.05 & 109.12 \\
\hline
\end{tabular*}
\caption{cost functions}
\label{Table:1}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Do you know how I can align the numbers to the center in each cell?

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\begin{tabular*}{0.9\textwidth}{|@{\extracolsep{\fill} }  c| r| r| r| r|}
\hline
Time - Angle & $45^{\circ}$ & $90 ^{\circ}$ & $180^{\circ} $ &  $360^{\circ}$ \\
\hline 
0.5 s & 44.22  & 192.71 & 1002.9  & 4118.2\\
\hline
1 s & 12.68 & 41.33  &  157.81 & 650.87 \\
\hline
2 s & 7.14 & 23.47 & 72.51 & 182.65\\
\hline
4 s & 4.41 &  14.43 & 32.05 & 109.12 \\
\hline
\end{tabular*}
%\renewcommand{\tablename}{Table 1}
\caption{cost functions}
\label{Table:1}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image: tblcorrected]